# TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property query as function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I'm trying to make a simple basic example of mocking a database driver (to be used in testing later):

```
'use strict';
import mysql from 'mysql';
import sinon from 'sinon';

let mock = sinon.mock(mysql);

mock.expects('query').withExactArgs(`DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myDatabase`).yields({ "fieldCount": 0, "affectedRows": 1, "insertId": 0, "serverStatus": 258, "warningCount": 0, "message": "", "protocol41": true, "changedRows": 0 });

mysql.query('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myDatabase');
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property query as function
```

Comment: it looks like from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction) that you use mysql.createConnection() to return a connection that then can call connection.query. Though I'm not too familiar with node mysql so I could be way off.

Comment: @ProfessorAllman You were correct, please post an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from the docs that you use mysql.createConnection() to return a connection that then can call connection.query.

```
'use strict';
import mysql from 'mysql';
import sinon from 'sinon';

let mock = sinon.mock(mysql.createConnection());

mock.expects('query').withExactArgs(`DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myDatabase`).yields({ "fieldCount": 0, "affectedRows": 1, "insertId": 0, "serverStatus": 258, "warningCount": 0, "message": "", "protocol41": true, "changedRows": 0 });

mysql.query('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myDatabase');
```